# Is it possible to create offline first apps with React-Native?

Tags: couchdb, offline, react-native, pouchdb

From what I've understood offline first apps need a way to tell if the user is connected; if not, it stores changes locally and syncs with the remote server when online.

The way I've found to do this with web apps is by using [pouchdb](http://pouchdb.com/) on the client communicating with an api connected to a [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) database. Or by using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html).

Is it possible to have similar functionality using React-Native? Maybe by using the [pouchdb-async-storage](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-async-storage) adapter. Are there other alternatives out there for local-remote data syncing?

Comment: According to user @modusjesus from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/3q8l6x/is_it_possible_to_create_offline_first_apps_with/):

It's extremely difficult because the runtime is suspended when the screen is locked. There hasn't been a solution to this yet.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? This is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Haven't been looking anymore... so I guess not.

Answer (score 3):

I build an AsycStorage Adapter for PouchDB, including Polyfills for React-native. Properly that helps.

[asyncstorage adapter for PouchDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-asyncstorage-down)

Comment: This might be exactly what we've been waiting for.

Comment: Project moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/stockulus/pouchdb-react-native) / [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually implemented offline capabilities in a React-Native app but from looking at the docs, the APIs provided enable you to do so.

The APIs you're looking for are [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#content) (for data persistence) and to detect the connection info use [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html#content).

You're on the right track about using pouchdb. The part you will most likely have to write yourself is the syncing script (I'm not sure you can do this in the background but I may be wrong).

Let me know how you get on or if you want to discuss further @hugo__df on twitter :)

Answer (score 1):

pouchdb-react-native is a good lib to look at